# Golang: Building and running with new directory structure

Tags: go, build

Brushing up on my golang, I see that there is a new recommended directory structure for go projects: We should be emitting the "src" directory from our project.
Here is an example of such a project: https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout , and I have also seen this mentioned in several recent articles.

Until now, I have created a package under /myproject/src/mypackage. Then, to run my project I would add /myproject to $GOPATH.

My question: If I use the new directory structure, how would I go about building and running my project? I could "hack" it by creating a symlink into a "src" directory... But that seems rather "dirty" (If I was going to do that, I could've just used "src" to begin with) .

I would appreciate if someone could point out the build and run commands for a project arranged in the structure mentioned above.

EDIT based on comments: This question is not about whether I want to use "src" or not. I definitely do want to embrace this new project structure. It's just that I cannot find instructions on how to build  and run a project with such a directory structure. For example: How would I reference the files in the pkg directory if it's not in my "$GOPATH/myproject/src"?

Comment: I think you read something wrong there, go hasn't changed the `$GOPATH/src/repo` pattern. The repo you've mentioned simple states that the code shouldn't have a `src` directory inside of it, as most java based projects do. Form the article **Don't confuse the project level /src directory with the /src directory Go uses for its workspaces**

Comment: @ishaan I still don't get it. When I wanted to use my project locally: It had a "src" directory inside it. So I could set my $GOPATH to point at my project. However, now  that the project has no "src" inside it, I can no longer set my $GOPATH to point at it. (because $GOPATH expects a src directory...). I might mention that I want to work "locally". I am not committing my code to github.com. I want to use the latest changes on my HDD. (I am just creating debug-builds on my local dev machine [before I push to github] )

Comment: There simply is *no* directory structure mandated, needed or recommended. Just use what fits your need (only thing: a folder named `internal` is for "internal packages only). You have to choose between GOPATH builds and module builds and that is is. How you cram your packages into the filesystem is of no concern. Just stick to How to Write Go Code and you'll be fine.

Comment: @Volker that is not true. I tried to rename "src" to "someotherdir". Then I used the same $GOPATH approach, and it was definetly looking for $GOPATH/src. It was not looking for $GOPATH/someotherdir. So a directory structure is definitly mandated when I use the $GOPATH approach for builds. HINT: I am well aware that I need to change my approach to building, and that is what this question is about: I am looking for an example on what a build command might look like.

Comment: Right, so you need $GOPATH/src but you don't need to point it to your code directory, instead can use the `/path/to/gohome` and have multiple repositories there. But what you were doing is also correct, albeit overkill. The article you're referencing isn't saying to not do that, it's saying you avoid using src in your codebase just because you did in in Java.

Comment: @ishaan It's not about correctness (or Java habits). It's about go. I *want* to use this new project structure. But I cannot get it to build or run. I have not found any examples of the build commands for this new structure online. I do not understand how I can go from having a project structure that does not have an "src" path, to an "src" path magically appearing in my $GOPATH after I build. What is this `/path/to/gohome` that you mention? I know only of $GOPATH and $GOROOT. Not sure what a "go home" would be...

Comment: @eshalev Sorry, but you are wrong. For GOPATH builds you code must live under $GOPATH/src but that is not the directory structure we are talking about here. GOPATH builds: Your code lives under $GOPATH/src and where is just a matter of taste (and tooling like go get).

Comment: @Volker, this phillosophical discussion is just causing more confusion. I do not want to use the old project structure. I want to use the new one. Can someone supply/link a material (non phillosophical) example of the commands to build and run such a project? A picture is worth a thousand words!

Comment: @eshalev You write "I want to use the new on [project structure]" but here is no new "project structure". How to Write Go Code is still accurate and nothing has changed. You can do GOPATH builds or module builds and project structure has no meaning.

Comment: @Volker I see that alot of modern projects have this new directory structure. I also don't like the redundant "src" in my project structure. People are obviously using this new project structure. This means that they are also *building* these *projects* and running them. I would like to *learn* how. That is why I am posting on stackoverlow

Comment: @eshalev You build every Go project with `go build <fullpackagepath>` or `go build` in the directory of the package. I have to admit I do not understand what your problem is.

Comment: How would I reference the files in the pkg directory if it's not in my "$GOPATH/myproject/src"? Makes no sense at all as you do not reference files.

Comment: Nothing in GoLang has changed, you used a method that was well... not recommended anyway. For Golang, put all your source inside a `src`, but the structure is `$GOPATH/src/repository` so all you do is, put multiple repositories inside src and don't need another src inside your own repo. Go automatically understands that. You don't need a separate path for all projects. Not sure why you started doing that in the first place, maybe for dependencies, but that is also solved with `deps ensure`. Go has been doing this since I started using it in 1.3

Comment: This makes a pretty strong assumption though: That my repository contains only one project. We are working on project which contains many many microservices. Each written in a different language (Python/Java/C/Go etc...) . From an administrative perspective, we are not using git submodules (as there would be too many of them). As such, my golang service cannot be top level in my repository. So I guess this means that I cannot use this new directory structure, right?

Comment: Yeah that is the assumption, but to be clear, it's not new. This is how go has always been. But for you, if you have a multi-language/multi-service repository, you have to do what you've done previously.

Comment: @ishaan this is misinformation. Since Go 1.11 and module support, projects no longer need to be under `$GOPATH/src`.